# How can I show custom text in mutt's status line?

Tags: mutt

Is there a command to echo/print/write/display a custom text in mutt's status line?

I have some custom filters (`<limit>` command). After setting a filter, I would like to display a description about the filter I just set, in order to identify it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `status_format` configuration variable in your muttrc, eg:

```
set status_format = "CUSTOM FILTER"
```

From within mutt, you can enter a colon and then the above.

To include in a macro:

```
set status_format = "CUSTOM FILTER"<enter>
```

To include other information in the status line (eg, number of messages/new messages etc etc), see [the formatting options for `status_format`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#status-format) in the Mutt manual.